# Why does Django admin try to encode strings into ASCII rather than Unicode? Or is this error something different than it looks like?

Tags: python, django, unicode, encoding, django-admin

I've got the following error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at
>   /admin/results_cop/copsegmentresult/
>
> Caught an exception while rendering:
>   ('ascii', 'ISU European Figure Skating
>   Championships 2009: Senior Ladies
>   Ladies: Short Program - 2. Susanna
>   P\xc3\x96YKI\xc3\x96', 98, 99,
>   'ordinal not in range(128)')

The fragment of the string that won't render is: PÖYKIÖ

What I don't get is why Django is trying to render the string as ASCII, why not UTF-8?

### EDIT 1:

I forgot to ask - I'd also quite like to know how to get rid of the error ;)

### EDIT 2:

Bobince's answer is correct :) I had something along the lines of:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s %s" (self.foo, self.bar)
```

Comment: can you provide your copsegmentresult model? does it have __unicode__() method or just __str__()?

Comment: Yes, please post the code where this is coming from. Django is quite capable of dealing with UTF-8, but you have to tell it that's what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you're asking Django to render a byte string. No `u` at the start of this:

```
'ISU European Figure Skating Championships 2009: Senior Ladies Ladies: Short Program - 2. Susanna P\xc3\x96YKI\xc3\x96'
```

So Django is probably trying to encode it to the page's encoding, presumably UTF-8. But byte strings can't be encoded directly; they have to be Unicode strings first. Python itself does this converting step using a default encoding which is typically `ascii`.

```
>>> 'P\xc3\x96YKI\xc3\x96'.encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError
```

So what you need to do is convert that byte string to a Unicode string yourself by UTF-8-decoding it, before it gets sent to the template. Where has it come from? Usually you should aim to keep all content strings inside your application as Unicode strings.

Comment: Thanks :) Changing the text to u"%s %s" did indeed solve the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is confused by bobince's answer, think of this:

The fields from the model are already in unicode format.

when you have a unicode function like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
  return "{0}".format(self.field_one)
```

It is actually returning a ASCII string(which means, it will try to convert field_one to ASCII), if the field_one contains characters outside of ASCII, you will get the problem as above.

Now consider this unicode function:

```
def __unicode__(self):
      return self.field_one
```

This works fine, because you are returning unicode string directly, no conversion needed.

Lets revisit the first **unicode** function, to make it work, you just need to add `u` to make it a unicode string

```
def __unicode__(self):
      return u"{0}".format(self.field_one)
```

Comment: This is true, but we hit in only on Chinese characters in our application. When you use `'%s' % (self.field)` - it worked for Polish characters from Unicode, as well as a couple other common cases. But for Chinese characters (not sure if traditional or simplified), from deep extended unicode (above 16-bit, or "plane 0"), this crashed. Never use `'{0}'.format()` in `__unicode__` - this crashes even for Polish characters. It's ok to stick to this answer, namely `u'{0}'.format(self.field.__unicode__())` - I sometimes add the method call explicitly.

Comment: django capture input in unicode, so
`>>> a = u"我"
>>> u"{}".format(a)
u'\u6211'`

Comment: I also found a kind of related documentation bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773816/why-python-str-format-doesnt-call-str