# Why python str.format doesn't call str()

Tags: python

I have the following class

```
class A(object):
  def __unicode__(self):
    return u'A'

  def __str__(self):
    return 'AA'

>>> u"{}".format(A())
u'A'
>>> "{}".format(A())
'AA'
>>> str(A())
'AA'
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html),

> "Harold's a clever {0!s}"        # Calls str() on the argument first

Why is this still return u'A' not u'AA'??

```
>>> u"{0!s}".format(A())
u'A'
```

I would expect it's the same as

```
>>> u"{}".format(str(A()))
u'AA'
```

Comment: because it is a unicode string?

Comment: Also, you should be returning strings from `__str__` and `__unicode__`, otherwise your program will fail.

Comment: haha sorry I don't know why I typed `print`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a (minor) documentation bug. `str.format` calls `str` if you pass the `!s` code in the format string, but `unicode.format` calls `unicode` instead.

The docs were probably written with Python 3 in mind, where all strings are Unicode and `!s` always calls `str`. The whole new formatting system was backported from Python 3.0 into Python 2.6, and it's not shocking that a few ambiguities slipped in through in the docs.

Comment: I think I agree. I'm raising an issue on the bug tracker for this.